# Odata - collection filter with contains

Tags: odata

Hello I would like to filter in this structure:

```
class User{
  public ICollection<Role> Roles{get; set}
}

class Role{
 public string Permissions{get; set;} //"User, Admin, Editor"
}
```

I would like to find users by permission. I tried this:
/odata/Users/?$filter=Roles/any(r: contains(r/Permissions, 'Admin'))

Here is exceptions:

> No function signature for the function with name 'contains' matches
>   the specified arguments. The function signatures considered are:
>   contains(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.String Nullable=true).

Where can be a problem? Can odata use this query? 
Thank you